# Set header to all $resource methods

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ng-resource in Angular to access a RESTful API. I created a simple factory to perform this.

```
.factory('Bookmark', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://bookmarks-angular.herokuapp.com/api/bookmarks/:id');
})
```

And in the controller I used `Bookmark.query`:

```
.controller('MainController', function($scope, Category, Bookmark){
    $scope.name = 'Carl';
    Category.getAll(function(data){
        $scope.categories = data.categories;
        $scope.currentCategory = data.categories[0];
        $scope.bookmarks = Bookmark.query();
    });
})
```

I need to use `Bookmark.save` and `Bookmark.remove`and also a token in the `Authorization` header. Searching this is the approach I have to use:

```
$resource('url/to/json', {}, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'something': 'anything' }
    }
});
```

But it works just to the get method and I want to use send the token in every `$resource` methods. I do not want to `overwrite` all the methods just to send this header. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an httpInterceptor, something like this from the angular docs:

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
    return {
      'request': function(config) {
          // add headers
          return config;
    }
}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

This might help you in creating interceptor.
http://ramanshankar.blogspot.in/2015/11/angularjs-http-interceptor.html

```js
var app = angular.module('simpleDirective', []);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
}]);

app.controller("DemoController", ['$rootScope','demoService', function($rootScope, demoService){
 $rootScope.message = [];
 $rootScope.message.push("In Demo Controller");
 demoService.functionOne();
}]);

app.service("demoService", ['$http','$rootScope',function($http, $rootScope){
 this.functionOne = function(){
  $http.get("temp.html")
  .success(function(data){
   $rootScope.message.push(data);
  })
  .error(function(data){
   $rootScope.message.push("Demo Service Error: "+data);
  });
 }
}]);

app.factory("httpInterceptor", function(){
  return{
    'request': function(config) {
      alert("request");
      return config;
    },

   'requestError': function(rejection) {
      alert("request error");
      return "Request error";
    },

    'response': function(response) {
      alert("response");
      return response;
    },

   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      alert("response error");
      return "response error";
    }
  }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="simpleDirective">
<div ng-controller="DemoController">  
<h2>AngularJS Interceptor Example</h2>  
<div ng-repeat="msg in message">  
 <div style="padding:5px;background:lightgrey;border:1px solid black;margin-bottom:10px;">{{msg}}</div>  
</div>  
</div>  
  </div>
```